# PHP7.0 - unable to load dynamic library oci8.so (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu, oracle-call-interface

After following the install instructions for oracle instant client, php is not able to load the oci8 extension.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst

I am getting an error.
**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so' - libmql1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0**

I have verified both oci8.so and libmql1.so locations.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If the `.so` library is in the path, it's possible it was built for a different architecture or version of PHP.  You could compile it for your system [from PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8). Another common issue is checking the wrong `php.ini` (they often differ for CLI and web server).

Comment: Are you using a server? How many PHP binaries to you have on your system?

Comment: I am using apache. I re-installed the oci using the rpms and now I see oci8 in the php cli `php -m | grep "oci8" but im still seeing that error in the web server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and php version 7.1

There are few directories  in `/usr/lib/php/`
for example

**20131226 for php5.6**

**20160303 for php7.1**

so problem with me that, the oci8 extension got installed on the wrong ( a user lib folder for php7.2) so I had to remove the php 7.2 completly

`sudo apt-get purge php7.2-common`

then I had uninstall the oci8 by running following command

```
sudo pecl uninstall oci8
```

and install again by running the following command

```
sudo pecl install oci8
```

To check the configuration loaded you do

```
php-config --extension-dir
```

And make sure that all extension are installed in the correct extension directory.

Make changes in the `/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini`

Check by running `phpinfo();` You must see this, ignore the cli if that stills gives you same error as your web shows the extension is getting loaded.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do, when I downgraded from PHP7.2 to 7.0.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding the following to `/etc/environment`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I followed this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/hewerthomn/81eea2935051eb2500941a9309bca703

Answer (score 0):

What I did was completely remove any installations of PHP and reinstall the version that I need.

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/59889/226518

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient_12_1/
```

I had the same problem, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting entire day for this small problem finally I came with this solution.
Sorry guys I am not champion is PHP but somehow I manage.
In my system I have CentOS 7 and PHP 7.4.XX.
I changed my LD_LIBRARY_PATH,
I have restarted my httpd service and checked phpinfo in browser (http://localhost/info.php),
Last I restared php-fpm service ........... and it's work for me.

Thanking you,
Anand