# Ubuntu wrong path to oci8.so

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu-16.04, oci8

I appreciate if anybody could point me a solution to a problem related to the installation of oracle oci8 in Ubuntu.
When i run `php -m | grep 'oci8'`.

I get :
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

The file is in `/usr/lib/php/20170718`. 
How can i fix this.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried to copy `oci8.so` file from `/usr/lib/php/20151012` to `/usr/lib/php/20170718`?

Comment: diferent error... i thinks the so file references other paths

Comment: Does it has correct permissions? And how did you install it? apt-get / PECL / from sources?

Comment: installed with pecl install oci8...as in https://gist.github.com/hewerthomn/81eea2935051eb2500941a9309bca703#file-install_oci8_ubuntu_16-04_php7-1-md

Comment: i add another installation before. thats why

Comment: What do you mean? That you tried to install it in other way before, not from pecl?

Comment: no i had everything working but i reinstall php and stop working , then a follow https://gist.github.com/hewerthomn/81eea2935051eb2500941a9309bca703#file-install_oci8_ubuntu_16-04_php7-1-md   again

Comment: I'd like to see that different error you get after copying `oci8.so` into `/usr/lib/php/20151012` directory. Probably something used in `oci8.so` is missing. Try to check it's dependencies with this command `ldd /usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so`. Then check if any of this files present in `/usr/lib/php/20170718` directory and copy it into `/usr/lib/php/20151012` if so.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/oci8.so: undefined symbol: zend_empty_string in Unknown on line 0...... ldd is ok

Comment: ldd result      linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe2d3ee000)
 libclntsh.so.12.1 => /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so.12.1 (0x00007fd32551d000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd325153000)
 libmql1.so => /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libmql1.so (0x00007fd324edd000)
 libipc1.so => /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libipc1.so (0x00007fd324b5f000)
 libnnz12.so => /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libnnz12.so (0x00007fd324455000)
 libons.so => /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libons.so (0x00007fd324210000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 

....

Comment: It looks like similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583721/2562686. I suggest you had PHP 7.2 and downgrade it to 7.0 then, right?

Comment: i had 7.0, upgrade to 7.2 and downgrade to 7.0 again

Comment: thanks for link .... its ok now...thank you very much ,

Comment: Bushikot      , answer question with your coment

Comment: You are wellcome! I've tagged your question as duplicate with link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583721/2562686